# How to convert genetic additive model from a binary to continuous variable to run a PheWAS in python

Tags: continuous, genetic-programming, genetics, genome

We are trying to run a PheWAS in the All of Us Researcher workbench using Python. The databse does not have any examples of converting the genetic additive model of binary variables (0/1, 1/1) to a continous variable (0, 1, 2) to denote the number of alleles an individual has. Does anyone have source code for this that we can adapt to use in All of Us? We are new to human computational genetics.

Thank you so much!